# how to add drawable xml file into radiobutton that is created using For loop

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

i know it is silly question but i m searching from 2 days and not able to get answer of this question 
i customized RadioButton so it will look good and it is working while i used drawable file into layout but i do not how to use/ get these files into my code. Right now RadioButton is creating using For Loop
here is how i m creating RadioButton

```
for(int i =0; i<ab.length;i++)
  {
    RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(this);
    radioButtonView.setText(ab[i]);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
  }
```

but i can use xml files in layout like this

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioAndroid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
    android:textColor="@drawable/rbtn_textcolor_selector" />
```

can anyone suggest how to get these files into my for loop so that RadioButton will looks good 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
for(int i =0; i<ab.length;i++)
  {
    RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(this);
    radioButtonView.setText(ab[i]);
    radioButtonView.setTextColor(R.color.color_name);
     radioButtonView.setBackGroundResource(R.drawable.rbtn_selector);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
  }
```

Comment: just one more question how to add this in xml or  java code  `android:button="@null"`  @Fahim

Answer (score 0):

U can use setBackgroundResource programmatically, like:

```
for(int i =0; i<ab.length;i++)
{
RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(this);
radioButtonView.setText(ab[i]);
XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(
            R.drawable.rbtn_textcolor_selector);
ColorStateList colors = ColorStateList.createFromXml(getResources(),
            parser);
radioButtonView.setTextColor(colors);
radioButtonView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rbtn_selector);
radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
```

}

Comment: and what about `android:textColor="@drawable/rbtn_textcolor_selector"` how can i use it within my for loop

Comment: problem already solve, can u please tell me how to get  how to add this in xml or java code   `android:button="@null"` @user543

Comment: use radioButtonView.setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());